# IAP on Android Unity project not initializing when not connected to a Google Play account

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

When I'm connected to a Google Play account on my android device, the IAP on my Unity project are initializing and working fine.

However, when I download my app and delete my Google account from my device, and try to launch the app I get the following error messages on logcat:

```
02-03 11:41:31.221: I/UnityIAP(20665): IAB helper created.
02-03 11:41:31.341: I/UnityIAP(20665): Starting in-app billing setup.
02-03 11:41:31.491: I/UnityIAP(20665): Billing service connected.
02-03 11:41:31.501: I/UnityIAP(20665): invoking callback
02-03 11:41:31.501: I/UnityIAP(20665): Checking for in-app billing 3 support.
02-03 11:41:31.521: I/UnityIAP(20665): onIabSetupFinished: 3
02-03 11:41:31.521: I/UnityIAP(20665): Failed to setup IAB. Notifying Unity...
```

I'm not sure this is normal behavior. Shouldn't the IAP initialize even if I'm not connected to a Google account? I'll add that I'm still connected to Internet.

Also, what's the meaning of the `3` in `onIabSetupFinished: 3`? Is this an error code? Can I find more details in the documentation?

Comment: onIabSetupFinished: 3 might just be a log of the number of products found

Comment: I don't think so, I only have 2 products.